# how to re-populating jsp page fields when errors are there in binding result after server side validations?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC based application in which i am handling server side validations using annoations and custom validator and handling errors using binding result.

On submit when validations fails, jsp page field values does not retain its value.

i am using the below code on the jsp

```
<spring:bind path="applicantDetails.name">
                    <input type="text" name="applicantDetails.name"
                        title='<fmt:message key="PERSON_NAME" />' maxlength="20" id="name" />
                </spring:bind>
```

On controller, i have something like:

```
public String submitDetails(
            @ModelAttribute("beanName") @Valid ManageBean manageBean,
            BindingResult result, HttpSession session, Model model)
            {
    MyBeanValidator validator = new MyBeanValidator ();
            validator.validate(manageBean, result);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "pageName";
            }
```

What do i need to do so that the values entered on the page appears in the text box.

Comment: what is signature of your controller method

Comment: @NeelamMehta: Updated in question.

Comment: what is beanIns in MyBeanValidator validator = new MyBeanValidator ();
            validator.validate(beanIns, result);

Comment: @NeelamMehta edited..it is managebean that is to be validated..